# Button.PerformClick() across thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

See this code:

```
    Imports System.Threading

    Private trd As Thread

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    trd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
    trd.IsBackground = True
    trd.Start()
  End Sub

Sub ThreadTask()
    Thread.Sleep(50)
    Button4.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click        
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

I'm trying to simulate a button click from a different thread, but the following error occurs: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll", at the Button4.PerformClick() line.

How can I use this function across threads?

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute UI commands on the same thread as the controls were created on. We can do this with a delegate. This can be done very easily with a lambda.

Replace `Button4.PerformClick()` with this:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub() Button4.PerformClick())
```